# Why do I get an error when attempting to invoke indexOf on a generic ArraySlice?

Tags: swift, generics

The following function finds the second index of a given item in Array of Int:

```
func secondIndexOf(item: Int, inArray array: Array<Int>) -> Int? {
    if let firstIndex: Int = array.indexOf(item) {
        let slice: ArraySlice<Int> = array.suffixFrom(firstIndex + 1)
        return slice.indexOf(item)
    }
    return nil
}
```

However, when I attempt to create a generic version of this function to find the second Equatable item, I get an error:

```
func secondIndexOf<T: Equatable>(item: T, inArray array: Array<T>) -> T? {
    if let firstIndex: Int = array.indexOf(item) {
        let slice: ArraySlice<T> = array.suffixFrom(firstIndex + 1)
        return slice.indexOf(item) // Cannot invoke 'indexOf' with an argument list of type '(T)'
    }
    return nil
}
```

Why is this not valid Swift code, and what is the expected argument list if not `(T)`?  Xcode autocomplete shows `indexOf(element: Comparable)` with which `T` should be compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is giving you a confusing error message here—it isn't actually concerned about the argument. The return value is the source of the problem, since you aren't returning a value of type `T`, but an index of the array. You just need to change your return type to `Int?`:

```
func secondIndexOf<T: Equatable>(item: T, inArray array: Array<T>) -> Int? {
    if let firstIndex: Int = array.indexOf(item) {
        let slice: ArraySlice<T> = array.suffixFrom(firstIndex + 1)
        return slice.indexOf(item)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Oh... of course!  Thank you.  The error message confused me.

Comment: The error message is improved a little bit in Swift 2.2: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/ef45c06738a7fddb48e6b3e6e97d409945d3e84d7e3befac7cf6034678baefd0

Comment: Now that you point it out, I suppose the return type should really be `Array<T>.Index?` rather than `Int`.

Comment: No need for that mess! Your function is generic over the array's element, not the type of collection. Arrays use `Int` as their index type, so it's okay (and simpler all around) to return that. (And `+ 1` is easier to read than `.successor()`, too.)